# How to use shopify graphql in standalone app(outside iframe)?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

When I try to access Shopify Admin API Graphql in embedded app it works fine. but when i make my app standalone(outside iframe. it will opens in new tab.) the Shopify Admin API Graphql is not working. it's not return any result. it show only loading... and here i attached my sample code.

**Imports**

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {Query} from 'react-apollo'
```

**GraphQL Query**

```
const GET_ORDERS_DETAIL = gql`
 query orderDetails{
  orders(first: 10) {
    edges{
      node{
        name
        createdAt
        customer{
          displayName
        }
        displayFulfillmentStatus
        subtotalPriceSet{
          shopMoney {
            amount
          }
        }
        currentTaxLines {
          ratePercentage
        }
        totalTaxSet{
          shopMoney {
            amount
          }
        }
        totalPriceSet {
          shopMoney {
            amount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

**Component**

```
class Index extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Query query={GET_ORDERS_DETAIL}>
              {({ data, loading, error }) => {
                if (loading) return <div>Loading…</div>;
                if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
          
                console.log(data)
                return(
                  <div>Done</div>
                )
              }}
            </Query>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you select and activate the APP as an embedded APP then you can't use it as a standalone public app. you need to change the settings into APP also to use it as a standalone app.

Comment: my requirement is to create standalone app. it work fine only API part not working in standalone app.

Comment: Embedded or not, GQL works fine. Architect your App correctly. If it works embedded, it works not embedded. The problem is not GQL, but how you setup your App.

Comment: @DavidLazar it's working for you? in standalone.

Comment: Yes. I have zero troubles using Shopify as either Embedded App or not. It has nothing to do with that. All you need is an API key and a proper API session and you can call the API.

Comment: It might be an error in creating the Shopify graphQL client. How do you set up the connection with the graphQL API?